# Trying to Run a Candlestick Graph that runs and updates every minute

Tags: python, math, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I want to run a candlestick LQD price graph that updates every minute. I want to be able to automate the process instead of clicking run and getting the values manually. Attached is my code, thank you!

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf  
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
import time from datetime import date, datetime  
import matplotlib.animation as animation  
import mplfinance as mpf

def animate(ival):
    data = yf.download(tickers='LQD', period= '1d', interval = '1m')
    data['minute'] = pd.to_datetime(data['minute'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    data.set_index('minute', inplace=True)
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=data.index, 
                            open=data['Open'],
                            high=data['High'],
                            low=data['Low'],
                            close=data['Close'], name = 'market data'))
    fig.update_layout(
        title='LQD Live Spread Evolution',
        yaxis_title='Spread over Benchmark')
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=15, label="15m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=45, label="45m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1, label="HTD", step="hour", stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=2, label="3h", step="hour", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        )
    )

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval= 60000)

mpf.show()
```